# Gigabyte not able to boot. Stuck in Aptio setup utility

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a Gigabyte P56 which has dual boot. Windows 10 came pre-installed. I had installed Ubuntu 16.04 and it was fine. Suddenly the system froze few days back and every time I try to boot it directly goes to BIOS setup screen.

**What have I tried so far?**

1. I logged into Ubuntu using liveUSB and did boot-repair. [Here is the log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tntKC9gJkN/). Unfortunately this didn't help.
2. I read that I could try changing to CSM in boot menu in BIOS, but I don't even see CMS option at all.

When I logged into Ubuntu using liveUSB I could see the harddrive files but SSD partition is not visible using `fdisk -lu`. SSD is where both Ubuntu and Windows were installed.

**Note**: Today suddenly once I was able to log in to Ubuntu properly and everything worked until the system froze.

Here is the output of `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb`

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

Disk /dev/sdb: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 88EE4600-D74B-445A-9A34-3539215CAA8A
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 5967 sectors (2.9 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1      1922275328      1953523711   14.9 GiB    8200  Linux swap
   2            2048       781252047   372.5 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   3       781252608      1386721357   288.7 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   4      1386723328      1922275327   255.4 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
```

Comment: Your sda shows this for sda: "Invalid MBR Signature found." Post this: `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` You are showing UEFI entries for both Windows & Ubuntu but they are reset as if drive with ESP was unplugged.

Comment: @oldfred  Actually, I have not opened any drives. I have updated the output of gdisk

Comment: Sorry is sda a flash drive. then command should be `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb`

Comment: I remember sda as the SSD where OS was installed. I can't find it now. sdb is HDD though

Comment: When you plug in a flash drive, systems often promote them. Then flash drive is sda & main drive becomes sdb. That is why Linux switched to UUIDs years ago as numbering by device is not always consistent.

Comment: Agree. but I can't see my SSD partition at all. I am guessing that is the reason I am not able to boot to any OS.  thoughts ?

Comment: Is SSD an NVMe device. Often both UEFI and SSD firmware need updates.

Comment: If I remember correctly it is M.2 SATA not NVMe. Since it is not detecting SSD in liveUSB, any suggestion as to how to go about updating firmware now?

Comment: Most SSD have Windows tools for SSD firmware. Samsung has both Windows & Linux, but the Linux tools are  in the commercial area. (last time I checked).

Comment: @oldfred I had a second at boot repair log. /dev/sdc is USB I guess as it has memory size 3.8GB.  /dev/sda could still be SSD but log wrongly shows only 1GB size. That data helps you in anyway?

Comment: Do you have another flash drive plugged in? Or maybe a memory card in a USB converter? Memory cards normally are MMC devices. Very new SSD may be NVMe devices.

Comment: No. There is no other USB attached. I am saying that it could be SSD based on some threads like [this](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2720685/ssd-wiped-shows-1mb.html)

Comment: Similar issues on same model. https://superuser.com/questions/1228577/ssd-shown-as-1073mb-instead-of-256gb